# How do I get my code to validate each line in file using a defined function

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this code to validate each line in a text file using a defined function. But when I launch the code, it prints every line in the file and validates only the last line. I've tried using `for line in` but it didn't work. Please how do I get the code to return a validated response for each line?

```py
def __main__():
    '''Program to validate NUBAN account'''
    print("Hello!")
    code = input("Enter the bank code:_")
    with open("nuban.txt") as nuban:
     account_number = nuban.read()
     if validate_nuban_account(code, account_number):
        response = "Valid"
     else:
        response = "Invalid"

     print(account_number, "is {}.".format(response))

def validate_nuban_account(bank_code, account_number):
    '''Validate Account Function'''
    result = False

    if len(bank_code.rstrip()) == 3 and len(account_number.rstrip()) == 10:
        nuban = bank_code + account_number[:-1]

        check_digit = int(account_number[9:10])
        nuban_array = []

        for i in range(0, len(nuban)):
            nuban_array.append(int(str(nuban[i])))
        nuban_sum = (nuban_array[0]*3 + nuban_array[1]*7 + nuban_array[2]*3
                     + nuban_array[3]*3 + nuban_array[4]*7 + nuban_array[5]*3
                     + nuban_array[6]*3 + nuban_array[7]*7 + nuban_array[8]*3
                     + nuban_array[9]*3 + nuban_array[10]*7 + nuban_array[11]*3)

        cal_check_digit = 10 - (nuban_sum%10)
        if cal_check_digit == 10:
            cal_check_digit = 0

        if check_digit == cal_check_digit:
            result = True
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

The text file contains 10 digit numbers separated with a new line. Example:

```
2073828191
8293829017
9102720819
8192729929
```

Comment: Example of the text file?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the file using `nuban.read()`, which reads the entire file contents into the string `account_number`. Then, you're only calling the validation function on this one string, so it treats the entire string as an account number, and returns false because its length is greater than 10.

As you mentioned, the `for line in file` construct is the right thing to use here. This would read the file one line at a time, and stores the line contents in the `line` variable. Your code could be written like:

```py
with open("nuban.txt") as nuban:
    for account_number in nuban:
        if validate_nuban_account(code, account_number):
           response = "Valid"
        else:
           response = "Invalid"

        print(account_number.strip(), "is {}.".format(response))
```

Note `account_number` here includes the newline symbol (`\n`) so it's necessary to `.strip()` it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file is full string.

```
with open("nuban.txt") as nuban:

    for account_number in nuban:
        if len(account_number) != 10:
            continue;

        if validate_nuban_account(code, account_number):
```

Comment: I replaced file.read() with file.readline() and added the for line in file construct, but it returns a "typeError: can only concatenate list ( not "int") to list" but when I add quotation marks to each line, for example, "1234567890" it validates the numbers line by line including the quotes which returns invalid response for every line. Please how do I solve this?

Comment: I think that you don't use file.readline(). you should use read.